# iPhone SDK: How to center map around a particular point?

Tags: iphone

New to MapKit. Having problems centering map around a specified point. Here is the code. Not sure why this is not working. We are expecting to see a map centered around Cincinnati, OH. What we are seeing is the default google map of the world.

Any help appreciated.

```
/ Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D mapCoords[2];
    mapCoords[0].latitude = 39.144057;
    mapCoords[0].latitude = -84.505484;
    mapCoords[1].latitude = 39.142984;
    mapCoords[1].latitude = -84.502534;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.2;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = mapCoords[0];
    region.span = span;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: all 4 are latitude.... change 2 of them to longitude...

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
mapCoords[0].latitude = 39.144057;
mapCoords[0].latitude = -84.505484;
mapCoords[1].latitude = 39.142984;
mapCoords[1].latitude = -84.502534;
```

To:

```
mapCoords[0].latitude = 39.144057;
mapCoords[0].longitude = -84.505484;
mapCoords[1].latitude = 39.142984;
mapCoords[1].longitude = -84.502534;
```

Comment: What is the difference? They look the same. I must be missing something?

Comment: Please disregard the previous comment, I see the typo. However, I changed it and I am still unable to center a region around a point. I am not sure why?


 [super viewDidLoad];
 
 CLLocationCoordinate2D mapCoords[2];
 mapCoords[0].latitude = 39.144057;
 mapCoords[0].longitude = -84.505484;
 mapCoords[1].latitude = 39.142984;
 mapCoords[1].longitude = -84.502534;
 
 MKCoordinateSpan span;
 span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
 span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
 
 MKCoordinateRegion region;
 region.center = mapCoords[0];
 region.span = span;
 
 [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my code and it works fine:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;

span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
span.longitudeDelta=0.2; 

CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = 39.144057;
location.longitude = -84.505484;

region.span=span;
region.center=location;

[mv setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mv regionThatFits:region];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a combination of the typos above and IB wiring problem.